# Why is my variable always being mutated inside this function (if the the function doesn't even touch it)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I retrieve an object from my api, save it in a variable an it's suposed to not being modified anymore but it's being modified unexpectedly

I checked the entire component, all the functions and the html too, to find where it's being modified but without success.
I already changed variables names too in the hope of being any variable conflict but without success too.
Keep in mind that I'm only posting this question because I have no clue about the problem (it can and probably is, some ignorance about javascript from me as a developer) so be kind

## The problematic funtion:

```
  addArtigo(artigoInStock: Artigo) {
    console.log('log 1:', this.assistenciaOpen.material[1].qty, this.material[1].qty); // log1: 2 2
    const artigo = { ...artigoInStock, qty: 1 };
    let materialQ = this.material;
    if (artigoInStock.qty > 0) {
      if (materialQ) {
        if (materialQ.findIndex(item => item.id === artigo.id) < 0) {
          materialQ = [...materialQ, artigo];
        } else {
          console.log('log 2:', this.assistenciaOpen.material[1].qty, this.material[1].qty); // log2: 2 2
          materialQ.map(
            itemQ => {
              if (+itemQ.id === +artigo.id) {
                itemQ.qty++;
                return itemQ;
              } else {
                return itemQ;
              }
            }
          );
          console.log('log 3:', this.assistenciaOpen.material[1].qty, this.material[1].qty); // log3: 3 3
        }
      } else {
        materialQ = [artigo];
      }
      const resultIndex = this.results.findIndex(result => result.id === artigo.id);
      this.results[resultIndex].qty = this.results[resultIndex].qty - artigo.qty;
      this.material = materialQ;
      this.modal = false;
    }
    console.log('log 4:', this.assistenciaOpen.material[1].qty, this.material[1].qty); // log4: 3 3
    // I was expecting log3 to be log3: 2 3 and log4:2 3
    // for some reason, after materialQ.map() the this.assistenciaOpen.material[1].qty change, unexpectedly, from 2 to 3 (mirroring the this.material[1].qty)
  }

}
```

## The full component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { map, concatMap, tap, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AutoUnsubscribe } from 'ngx-auto-unsubscribe';

import { Assistencia, Artigo } from 'src/app/shared/models';
import { PrintService } from 'src/app/pages/dashboard-page/prints/print.service';
import { UIService, UI } from 'src/app/shared/state/ui.service';
import { AssistenciasService, ArtigosService } from 'src/app/shared/state';
import { Observable, concat, of } from 'rxjs';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@AutoUnsubscribe()
@Component({
  selector: 'app-assistencia-page',
  templateUrl: './assistencia-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./assistencia-page.component.scss']
})
export class AssistenciaPageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public assistenciaOpen: Assistencia;
  public modal = false;
  public artigoSearchForm = this.fb.group({
    input: [null]
  });
  public results: Artigo[];
  public material: Partial<Artigo>[];

  constructor(
    private printService: PrintService,
    private uiService: UIService,
    private assistencias: AssistenciasService,
    private artigos: ArtigosService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap
      .pipe(
        concatMap((params: ParamMap) => this.assistencias.getAndWatch(+params.get('id'))),
        map((res: Assistencia[]) => res[0]),
        concatMap(
          assistencia => {
            let assistMaterial: Partial<Artigo>[];
            typeof assistencia.material === 'string'
              ? assistMaterial = JSON.parse(assistencia.material)
              : assistMaterial = assistencia.material;
            if (assistMaterial) {
              return concat(
                assistMaterial.map(
                  (artigo: Partial<Artigo>) => {
                    return this.artigos.get(artigo.id)
                      .pipe(
                        map((res: Artigo[]) => res[0]),
                        map(res => res = { ...res, qty: artigo.qty })
                      );
                  }
                )
              ).pipe(
                concatMap(concats => concats),
                toArray(),
                map( material => ({...assistencia, material})));
            } else {
              return of(assistencia);
            }
          }
        ),
        tap( assistencia => this.assistenciaOpen = assistencia)
      )
      .subscribe(
        (assistencia) => {
          console.log(assistencia);
          console.log('init');
          this.material = assistencia.material;
        }
      );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() { }

  saveChangesOnStock(material: Partial<Artigo>[], assistMaterial: Partial<Artigo>[]) {
    if (material) {
      console.log(material);
      return concat(material.map(
        (artigo: Artigo) => this.artigos.get(artigo.id)
          .pipe(
            map(res => res[0]),
            concatMap(
              (dbArtigo: Artigo) => {
                const artigoToSave = { id: dbArtigo.id, qty: dbArtigo.qty - (artigo.qty) };
                return this.artigos.patch(dbArtigo.id, artigoToSave);
              }
            )
          )
      )).pipe(concatMap(a => a), toArray());
    } else {
      console.log(null);
      return of(null);
    }
  }

  saveAssistencia(newEstado: string, assistencia: Assistencia) {
    if (newEstado !== 'em análise' && !assistencia.relatorio_cliente) {
      return alert('Preenche o relatório para o cliente!');
    }
    return this.saveChangesOnStock(this.material, null)
      .pipe(
        concatMap(
          _ => this.assistencias.patch(assistencia.id, { ...assistencia, estado: newEstado, material: this.material })
            .pipe(
              tap(() => {
                if (newEstado === 'entregue') { this.printService.printAssistenciaSaida(assistencia); }
              }),
              tap(() => window.history.back())
            )
        )
      ).subscribe();
  }

  openNewAssistenciaWithThisData(assistencia: Assistencia) {
    this.uiService.patchState(
      {
        // modals
        // pages
        assistenciasCriarNovaPageContactoClienteForm: {
          contacto: assistencia.cliente_user_contacto
        },
        assistenciasCriarNovaPageCriarNovaForm: {
          ...assistencia,
          problema: `(Ficha anterior: ${assistencia.id}) `,
          orcamento: null
        },
        // prints
      }
    )
      .subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/assistencias-criar-nova']));
  }

  navigateBack() {
    window.history.back();
  }

  searchArtigo(input?: string) {
    if (input) {
      const inputSplited = input.split(' ');
      const inputMapped = inputSplited.map(word =>
        '{"$or": [' +
        '{ "marca": { "$like": "%' + word + '%" }},' +
        '{ "modelo": { "$like": "%' + word + '%" }},' +
        '{ "descricao": { "$like": "%' + word + '%" }}' +
        ' ]}'
      );
      const dbQuery =
        '{' +
        '"query": {' +
        '"$limit": "200",' +
        '"$and": [' +
        inputMapped +
        ']' +
        '}' +
        '}';

      this.artigos
        .findAndWatch(JSON.parse(dbQuery))
        .pipe(
          map((artigos: Artigo[]) => {
            if (this.material) {
              artigos.map(
                artigo => {
                  const id = this.material.findIndex(item => item.id === artigo.id);
                  if (id > 0) {
                    console.log(
                      'id:' + id,
                      artigo.qty,
                      this.material[id].qty,
                      this.assistenciaOpen.material[id].qty,
                      artigo.qty - (this.material[id].qty - this.assistenciaOpen.material[id].qty));
                    artigo.qty = artigo.qty - (this.material[id].qty - this.assistenciaOpen.material[id].qty);
                    return artigo;
                  } else {
                    return artigo;
                  }
                }
              );
              return artigos;
            } else {
              return artigos;
            }
          })
        )
        .subscribe((res: Artigo[]) => this.results = res);
    }
  }

  addArtigo(artigoInStock: Artigo) {
    console.log(this.assistenciaOpen.material[1].qty, this.material[1].qty);
    const artigo = { ...artigoInStock, qty: 1 };
    let materialQ = this.material;
    if (artigoInStock.qty > 0) {
      if (materialQ) {
        if (materialQ.findIndex(item => item.id === artigo.id) < 0) {
          materialQ = [...materialQ, artigo];
        } else {
          materialQ.map(
            itemQ => {
              if (+itemQ.id === +artigo.id) {
                itemQ.qty++;
                return itemQ;
              } else {
                return itemQ;
              }
            }
          );
        }
      } else {
        materialQ = [artigo];
      }
      const resultIndex = this.results.findIndex(result => result.id === artigo.id);
      this.results[resultIndex].qty = this.results[resultIndex].qty - artigo.qty;
      this.material = materialQ;
      this.modal = false;
    }
    console.log(this.assistenciaOpen.material[1].qty, this.material[1].qty);
  }

}
```

## HTML

```html
<div *ngIf="!assistenciaOpen">
  <span class="spinner spinner-inline">
  </span>
  <span>
    A carregar dados...
  </span>
</div>

<div *ngIf="assistenciaOpen as assistencia">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-icon" style="margin:0; padding:0" (click)="navigateBack()">
    <clr-icon class="is-solid" size="36" shape="arrow" style="transform: rotate(270deg);"></clr-icon>
  </button>

  <h3>Assistência {{assistencia.id}}</h3>

  <div class="separate">
    <div class="clr-row">
      <div class="clr-col-md-2 fontheavy">
        Estado:
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col">
        {{assistencia.estado}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="separate">
    <div class="clr-row">
      <div class="clr-col-md-2 fontheavy">
        Cliente:
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col">
        {{assistencia.cliente_user_name}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr-row">
      <div class="clr-col-md-2 fontheavy">
        Técnico:
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col">
        {{assistencia.registo_cronologico[assistencia.registo_cronologico.length-1].tecnico}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr-row">
      <div class="clr-col-md-2 fontheavy">
        Equipamento:
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col">
        {{assistencia.categoria}}
        {{assistencia.marca}}
        {{assistencia.modelo}}
        {{assistencia.cor}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr-row">
      <div class="clr-col-md-2 fontheavy">
        Serial:
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col">
        {{assistencia.serial}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr-row">
      <div class="clr-col-md-2 fontheavy">
        Problema:
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col">
        {{assistencia.problema}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="separate">
    <div class="clr-row">
      <div class="clr-col">
        <div class="clr-row">
          <div class="clr-col">
            <button class="btn btn-link" (click)="modal = true">Adicionar material</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clr-row" *ngIf="material">
          <div class="clr-col">
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="left">Qty</th>
                  <th>Descrição</th>
                  <th>Local</th>
                  <th class="left">Custo p/ unidade</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let artigoY of material">
                  <td class="left">{{artigoY.qty}}</td>
                  <td>{{artigoY.descricao}} {{artigoY.marca}} {{artigoY.modelo}}</td>
                  <td>{{artigoY.localizacao}}</td>
                  <td class="left">{{artigoY.preco | currency: 'EUR'}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="separate">
    <div class="clr-row">
      <div class="clr-col-md-6">
        <div class="clr-row">
          <div class="clr-col fontheavy">
            Informação técnica interna:
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clr-row">
          <div class="clr-col">
            <!--
            <textarea name="relatorio_interno" id="relatorio_interno" [attr.readonly]="assistencia.estado === 'contacto pendente'
                || assistencia.estado === 'não atendeu p/ cont.'
                || assistencia.estado === 'cliente adiou resp.'
                || assistencia.estado === 'orçamento pendente'
                || assistencia.estado === 'não atendeu p/ orç.'
                || assistencia.estado === 'cliente adiou orç.'
                || assistencia.estado === 'aguarda material'
                || assistencia.estado === 'concluído'
                || assistencia.estado === 'entregue'" [(ngModel)]='assistencia.relatorio_interno'></textarea>
              -->
            <textarea name="relatorio_interno" id="relatorio_interno"
              [(ngModel)]='assistencia.relatorio_interno'></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col-md-6">
        <div class="clr-row">
          <div class="clr-col fontheavy">
            Informação para o cliente:
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clr-row">
          <div class="clr-col">
            <textarea name="relatorio_cliente" id="relatorio_cliente"
              [(ngModel)]='assistencia.relatorio_cliente'></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="separate">
    <div class="clr-row">
      <div class="clr-col-md-2 fontheavy">
        Orçamento:
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col">
        <span *ngIf="assistencia.orcamento">€ {{assistencia.orcamento}}</span>
        <span *ngIf="!assistencia.orcamento">não tem</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr-row">
      <div class="clr-col-md-2 fontheavy">
        Preço:
      </div>
      <div class="clr-col-md-4">
        €<input type="number" name="preco" id="preco" [(ngModel)]='assistencia.preco'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="separate">

    <div *ngIf="assistencia.estado === 'recebido'
          || assistencia.estado === 'em análise'
          || assistencia.estado === 'contactado'
          || assistencia.estado === 'incontactável'
          || assistencia.estado === 'orçamento aprovado'
          || assistencia.estado === 'orçamento recusado'
          || assistencia.estado === 'material recebido'">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-icon" (click)="saveAssistencia('em análise', assistencia)">
        <clr-icon class="is-solid" shape="floppy" flip="vertical"></clr-icon>
        Guardar
      </button>
      <clr-dropdown>
        <button clrDropdownTrigger class="btn btn-outline-primary">+ Opções <clr-icon shape="caret down"></clr-icon>
        </button>
        <clr-dropdown-menu clrPosition="top-left" *clrIfOpen>
          <button clrDropdownItem (click)="saveAssistencia('orçamento pendente', assistencia)">Orçamentar
          </button>
          <button clrDropdownItem (click)="saveAssistencia('contacto pendente', assistencia)">Contactar
          </button>
          <button clrDropdownItem (click)="saveAssistencia('concluído', assistencia)">Concluir</button>
        </clr-dropdown-menu>
      </clr-dropdown>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="assistencia.estado === 'orçamento pendente'
          || assistencia.estado === 'não atendeu p/ orç.'
          || assistencia.estado === 'cliente adiou orç.'">
      <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="saveAssistencia('orçamento aprovado', assistencia)">Aceite</button>
      <clr-dropdown>
        <button clrDropdownTrigger class="btn btn-outline-primary">+ Opções <clr-icon shape="caret down"></clr-icon>
        </button>
        <clr-dropdown-menu clrPosition="top-left" *clrIfOpen>
          <button clrDropdownItem (click)="saveAssistencia('orçamento recusado', assistencia)">Recusado
          </button>
          <button clrDropdownItem (click)="saveAssistencia('cliente adiou orç.', assistencia)">Cliente adiou
            resposta</button>
          <button clrDropdownItem (click)="saveAssistencia('não atendeu p/ orç.', assistencia)">Não atendeu
          </button>
          <button clrDropdownItem (click)="saveAssistencia('incontactável', assistencia)">Incontactável
          </button>
        </clr-dropdown-menu>
      </clr-dropdown>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="assistencia.estado === 'contacto pendente'
          || assistencia.estado === 'não atendeu p/ cont.'
          || assistencia.estado === 'cliente adiou resp.'">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="saveAssistencia('contactado', assistencia)">
        Sucesso
        <clr-icon shape="caret down"></clr-icon>
      </button>
      <clr-dropdown>
        <button clrDropdownTrigger class="btn btn-outline-primary">+ Opções <clr-icon shape="caret down"></clr-icon>
        </button>
        <clr-dropdown-menu clrPosition="top-left" *clrIfOpen>
          <button type="button" (click)="saveAssistencia('contactado', assistencia)" clrDropdownItem>Cliente adiou
            resposta</button>
          <button type="button" (click)="saveAssistencia('não atendeu p/ cont.', assistencia)" clrDropdownItem>Não
            atendeu</button>
          <button type="button" (click)="saveAssistencia('incontactável', assistencia)"
            clrDropdownItem>Incontactável</button>
        </clr-dropdown-menu>
      </clr-dropdown>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="assistencia.estado === 'concluído'">
      <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="saveAssistencia('entregue', assistencia)">
        Entregar
      </button>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="assistencia.estado === 'entregue'">
      <button class="btn" (click)="openNewAssistenciaWithThisData(assistencia)">
        Receber Novamente
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<clr-modal [(clrModalOpen)]="modal" [clrModalSize]="'lg'">
  <h3 class="modal-title">Adicionar Material ( Em construção...)</h3>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form [formGroup]="artigoSearchForm" (ngSubmit)="searchArtigo(artigoSearchForm.value.input)">
      <div class="clr-row">
        <div class="clr-col-12 padding-bottom-05">
          <input type="text" class="wd-100" placeholder="Digita algo..." name="input" formControlName="input" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <h4>Resultados:</h4>
    <div *ngIf="results as artigos">
      <div *ngIf="artigos.length===0"> Não encontrei nada... Tenta novamente com atenção.</div>
      <div *ngIf="artigos.length>0">
        <r-data-row class="clr-row" *ngFor="let artigo of artigos; let listaIndex=index" (click)="addArtigo(artigo)">
          <div class="clr-col-lg-3">
            <span class="fontheavy">{{artigo.marca}}</span>
            {{artigo.modelo}}
          </div>
          <div class="clr-col-lg-6 lessimportant">
            {{artigo.descricao}}
          </div>
          <div class="clr-col-lg-1 lessimportant">
            Qty: {{artigo.qty}}
          </div>
          <div class="clr-col-lg-2 lessimportant">
            Local: {{artigo.localizacao}}
          </div>
        </r-data-row>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</clr-modal>
```

I expct that this.assistenciaOpen is only modified 1 time (when i subscribe to api on ngOnInit() method

Comment: I don't because i'm listening to changes on api over websockets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found what was wrong in my code and I'm posting the solution so that it can help others later.
As I suspected the problem was created by my ignorance of how javascript copies objects.

### Explanation

Despite some errors in the function above
(as the:
-> incorrect using of `.map()` method
-> using increment oprerator inside `.map()`
-> plus the fact that I don't recomend using the `++increment` and `--decrement` arithmetic operators anywhere at all because of its unpure behaviour)

I was fully ignorant about how javascript copies it's objects.

In javascript, when you copy values from primitive types (`Number` `String` `Boolean` `undefined` and `null`) you're creating a copy of the values on to the new variable.
When you copy `objects` (as `object`, `array`, etc...) you actually just creating, in the new variable, a reference to the old variable.

So when you mutate the copy of a variable, you're actually mutating the original variable.

### Example of problem

```
const a = 4;
const b = a; // b = 4
++b;
console.log(a, b); // 4 5
```

```
const car = {
    motor: {
        fuel: 'gas',
        intake: 'compressor'
    },
    color: red
};
const otherCar = car;
otherCar.motor.intake = 'turbo';

console.log(car.motor.intake); // turbo
console.log(otherCar.motor.intake); // turbo
```

### Solution

To solve this problem I found many solutions, from which I'll point 2:
1 - Use a library as **immutablejs** to ensure immutability (which if you use typescript will be very difficult to implement, if you want to use `immutable.Map` objects with types, wich is the main reason we all use typescript)
2 - Use `...` **Spread operator** to copy **1 level** objects or [Ramda.clone](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#clone) for **deep cloning** when is needed to copy **nested objects**

### Warning

You can use a library as **Ramdajs** to make **deep copies** of your nested objects but use it wiselly because deep copies have an **impact on performance**.
In my case, where I'm building a medium sized webApp, I haven't noticed anything anyway but it's important to know that.

### Bonus

You can read [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/copying-stuff-in-javascript-how-to-differentiate-between-deep-and-shallow-copies-b6d8c1ef09cd/) on freecodecamp.com to know more about how javascript handles copying

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of is this

> tap( assistencia => this.assistenciaOpen = assistencia)

Can you change this to

> tap( assistencia => {console.log("Got a value"); this.assistenciaOpen
>   = assistencia})

if you see a *Got a value* between those two console dumps, then that would be the reason.Add logic here to handle this re-assignment.

Comment: if you check some lines down you will see in the .subscribe() that i do a console.log to know when new values arrive from api

Comment: can you try 

tap( assistencia => this.assistenciaOpen = Object.assign({}, assistencia))

Comment: I tried that, as you said, some minutes ago but didn't solve the problem too. I really believe that this problem is or a  bug from typescript or any rule/good pratice of programing javascript that I'm doing wrong. I debugged the app with vscode chrome debug extension and the value always mutate precisely after `materialQ.map()` inside the `addArtigo()`